# SpreadsheetApp.getActive() returns null but a sheet is open

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I hope some one can help me.

I have make a script for the first time and it works.
After that i publish it in the market only for my organisation.

I install the add on and open a sheet.
In that sheet i can open the side bar that i have create an try to run a function.

That function start with  `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();`
This will return `null`.

I have the follow code:

```html
Function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen();
}

function onOpen() // show a sidebar in the sheet

{
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('OCD Mailing')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

  ///////////////////////////////Show side bar///////////////////////////////////////////
function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('SideBar OCD MM')
      .setTitle('Mail Merge OCD V0.8')
      .setWidth(300);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}

/////////////////////////////////////Kopieer sheet////////////////////////////////

function Kopieersheets(){
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  Logger.log( currentSheet );
var url = currentSheet.getUrl();
Logger.log( url );
}
```

This add-on needs to be available for all the users. Thea are not allowed to create scripts.

- Screenshot error (View)

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that the add-on you have is available to your organization **and** you published in the GSuite Marketplace, seems like the missing step here is using the  `onInstall(e)` trigger.

According to the Apps Script triggers [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#getting_started):

> onInstall(e) runs when a user installs an Editor add-on from within Google Docs, Sheets, Slides, or Forms.

Therefore, if the `var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` line is located in an `onOpen(e)` trigger, you will just need to add this:

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

Comment: Thank you fore you're reaction.
I add the onInstall(e) trigger but it will not help.

I can run the script from the script editor but then i get also the Null value.
While i heve a sheet open in a browser.

Comment: Do you have an `onOpen` trigger as well? Try closing and reopening the sheet as this will trigger the `onOpen`. Also, where exactly in your code did you log the values you mentioned in your question?

Comment: How did you deploy and later installed the add-on? @NikivanGog

Comment: I deploy it in my Private free google account. Later i set it to G-suite.
So if you see in the code i have a side bar. This one is opening when you open it in the menu.

Comment: Did you set all the necessary permissions in this situation? Can you provide more details about the deployment process and how you installed it? Moreover, did you authorize it?